# Customer Grid - Split Address Lines

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, grid

I've got some code in place on the Customer Grid that feeds in `default_billing` address lines:

```
->joinAttribute('billing_street', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
```

I need to know how to split these into separate columns, for example instead of having "Address 1 Address 2" in the same column I need - | Address 1 | Address 2 | in 2 different columns.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a column renderer?

Comment: I am now, following from Matthias Zeis' answer below, but I wasn't before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I do understand correctly you would like to have two "true" separated columns.

Here is a quick solution.

Join the billing street two times in `_prepareCollection()` of your grid so you can use them as separate columns:

```
->joinAttribute('billing_street_first_line', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
->joinAttribute('billing_street_second_line', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
```

Define the two columns in `_prepareColumns()` of your grid:

```
$this->addColumn('billing_street_first_line', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Billing Street First Line'),
    'width'     => '150',
    'index'     => 'billing_street_first_line',
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterFirstLine'),
    'renderer' => 'mzeis_grid/adminhtml_widget_grid_column_renderer_address_firstline'
));

$this->addColumn('billing_street_second_line', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Billing Street Second Line'),
    'width'     => '150',
    'index'     => 'billing_street_second_line',
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterSecondLine'),
    'renderer' => 'mzeis_grid/adminhtml_widget_grid_column_renderer_address_secondline',
    'sortable' => false
));
```

Notice that I disabled sorting on the second line as this isn't possible with my suggestion. With a little bit more time you may be able to work out a sortable solution, though.

Add the two filter condition callback methods in your grid in order to be able to filter for the columns. The syntax may be MySQL-specific but you may get away with it as long as you don't plan to use other databases:

```
protected function _filterFirstLine($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return;
    }
    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("SUBSTRING_INDEX(`at_billing_street_first_line`.`value`, \"\\n\", 1) LIKE ?", '%' . $value . '%');
}

protected function _filterSecondLine($collection, $column)
{
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return;
    }
    $sql = $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->__toString();
    $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("SUBSTRING_INDEX(`at_billing_street_second_line`.`value`, \"\\n\", -1) LIKE ?", '%' . $value . '%');
}
```

And finally, create the two renderer classes for rendering the first line in the one column and the second line in the other column. Let's assume that your Extension is called `Mzeis_Grid` and has been configured to be in the `local` code pool. In the `config.xml` you write:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mzeis_grid>Mzeis_Grid_Block</mzeis_grid>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Your first column renderer, `app/code/local/Mzeis/Grid/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Address/Firstline.php`:

```
<?php

class Mzeis_Grid_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Address_Firstline extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Text
{
    public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value = parent::_getValue($row);
        $lines = explode("\n", $value);
        return $lines[0];
    }
}
```

Your second column renderer, `app/code/local/Mzeis/Grid/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Address/Secondline.php`:

```
<?php

class Mzeis_Grid_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Address_Secondline extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Text
{
    public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value = parent::_getValue($row);
        $lines = explode("\n", $value);
        if (count($lines) > 1) {
            return $lines[1];
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine in the grid. However, I get an error when I try to export to CSV - I've had the same with Renderers before! Cannot send headers; headers already sent in .../Firstline.php, line 1
 -- I've checked all the usual causes of this (Empty spaces etc etc)

Comment: Do you want these columns to be in the CSV export too or would it be okay if they don't show up there?

Comment: Yes, I need them to show in the CSV export too.

Comment: I just tried, I can export my rows without problems. Could it be that the problem is somewhere else if you had it before? You could create another question for that.

Comment: I created a question before, but didn't find a solution. Where have you put your Renderers, I have them in a different location so perhaps that's the problem? Mine are in: app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Renderer

Comment: I expanded the explanation above. I hope it helps you. Basically you have to handle the column renderers like any other block class. You have to define the beginning ot the block class names for your alias (`mzeis_grid` in my example) and then you have to put the block class in your extension folders. `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Renderer` will only work if your class name starts with `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Renderer`.

Comment: Hmm, yes. My class name is: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Renderer_Firstline - I'll try set this up as an extension and see if it helps.
The code itself on the Grid works fine, it's just when I try to export to CSV

Comment: The CSV export problem is another issue, especially if you also had the problem elsewhere before. I can export the rows just fine. If the columns work fine please can you accept the answer so we get the answer rate up (this is important as Magento Stack Exchange is still in Beta)?

Comment: Sorry, thought I had already accepted it! Do you think the headers already sent on CSV export is related to the file being in `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Renderer` and not in it's own extension?